# how get the data from hyperledgerfabric ledger and update

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

// ============================================================================================================================
// write() - genric write variable into ledger
//
// Shows Off PutState() - writting a key/value into the ledger
//
// Inputs - Array of strings
//    0   ,    1
//   key  ,  value
//  "abc" , "test"
// ============================================================================================================================
func write(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var value,key string
    var err error
    var keys  = 1
```

The following is my write method in hyperledger fabric i have assigned the keys = 1

2) Always  my method is making the keys = 1 so i should get the key from fabric and assign it to keys variable can anyone help me with this ISSUE or  provide any documention how to do that

Comment: Is it version 1.0 or 0.6?

Comment: my version is 0.6

Comment: Then you should return error too.Like below

Answer (score 1):

You should retun error with version 0.6 fabric chaincode.

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) write(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
logger.Debug("Entering chaincode")

if len(args) < 2 {
    logger.Error("Invalid number of args")
    return nil, errors.New("Expected atleast two arguments")
}
someObj := ObjectGet{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(Input1), &someObj)
s1, _ := json.Marshal(someObj)
err = stub.PutState(variable1, []byte(s1))
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Could not save record to ledger", err)
    return nil, err
}


return nil, nil
}
```

Comment: type ObjectGet struct { Variable1 string `json:"variable1"`}  this you have to declare as a structure on the top of the chaincode file.I would suggest ,go for version 1.0 chaincode fabcar example.Its more intuitive and easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot can we chat in stack exchange  i have update my code  can you plese see it

Comment: I am in office now .Could you please ping post 7 at nsinghdeo005@gmail.com?

Comment: Your company allows that?

Comment: Ping me at around 7 pm